# How to display a current user only in django user form

Tags: python, django

```
class Book(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='books/pdfs/')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.description

   def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.pdf.delete()
      super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

  #forms.py
 class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
         super(BookForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ('description', 'pdf', 'user')
```

When i run an application it shows all the users, I want to restrict to only current user who is logged in.[image: User form image]

Comment: Why using a form field then? Just save the current user.

Comment: Because i need to filter data then based on user logged in.

Comment: Why don't put the logged user in a hidden field?

Comment: So, you don't want to see *the logged in user* but *all logged in users*. That can be  complicated since HTTP is stateless and you can't even say if someone is logged out of not. So, what is your technical definition of `logged in`?